# Can we link mutiple accounts with same phone number and having phone no. to be a authentication method?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm setting up a school management system, wherein, phone number to be linked with multiple accounts (e.g., parent and more than one child). Being phone number is authentication method, how can we link these account to single phone number and still have this go through? Can we setup an unique ID along with OTP (linked to the account)?

possible solution to tackle this challenge

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Firebase Authentication [phone number provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) can only associate a phone number with a single account. It would have no way to distinguish between those accounts if they had the same phone number as their primary identification.

If you want to use the same phone number with multiple accounts, the only way to do that in Firebase would be to implement a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) for it.

Comment: Thank you. Frank! I'll explore custom auth system and see how it can help tackle this issue